# Eslint giving error on the first line of file

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint, prettier-eslint

[image]

What is this error on the first line of the file it came up on every file and when I hover over it, it says:

```
Parsing error: require() of ES Module F:\web\React Native\dog_food\node_modules\eslint-scope\lib\definition.js from F:\web\React Native\dog_food\node_modules\babel-eslint\lib\require-from-eslint.js not supported.
Instead change the require of definition.js in F:\web\React Native\dog_food\node_modules\babel-eslint\lib\require-from-eslint.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.eslint
```

Comment: Did you try restarting VSCode?

Comment: Can you share content of the .eslintrc.js file.

Comment: Maybe try to set `"module": "ESM"` in your package.json ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you use deprecated `babel-eslint` parser, try to install `@babel/eslint-parser` and add it to field "parser" at eslint config file

```
$ yarn remove babel-eslint
$ yarn add --dev @babel/eslint-parser
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  ...
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  ...
}
```

and reload your IDE